# How to debug maasserver with django runserver

Tags: maas

In order to debug maas, I ran the following command:

```
$ cd /usr/share/pyshared/maas
$ sudo python manage.py runserver (IP):8888 --settings=maas.settings
```

After that, I typed the url 'http://(IP):8888/MAAS/' in a firefox browser.
Then the following error is shown:

```
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.
```

It seems that server did not find homepage 404.html.

When I check with url `http://(IP):8000(Not 8888)/MAAS/`', number of nodes are increased 2 times when manager.py runserver is running.

Could you let me know how to debug maas/maasserver using pdb and django runserver ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to enable the debugging options in /etc/maas/maas_local_settings.py.

What version of MAAS are you using?